# Net Profit Bug in Strategy Tester

Tags: pine-script

I have the following strategy:

```
strategy("MyStrategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = 0,
  default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100,
  initial_capital = 10000)
```

When I run a test, I get a net profit of $32,819 (328.19%).

However, if I change `initial_capital` to `1`, the net profit reports as $32,819 (3,281,900%).

with `default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity` and `default_qty_value=100`, I would expect the net profit percentage to remain the same regardless of the initial capital.

If it matters, here is how I am entering my positions:

```
strategy.entry("myTrade", false, when=myCondition and strategy.position_size == 0,
  comment="myComment", qty=100)
```

Removing the `qty=100` parameter causes the test to fail with "No data."

Comment: When you specify qty for entry/exit explicitly it overrides the default ones.

Comment: Please see the last line of the question

Comment: This means that initial capital size is not enough for buy at least 1 contract. Try to increase initial capital size